# Searching for an Integer in an Output File C++

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a menu driven program in C++ and I'm having a little difficulty searching for a certain int in an Output file. My function looks like this.

```
int studentId;
int searchId;
double examGrade1, examGrade2, examGrade3;
ifstream readGrades;

do
{
    cout << "Enter the student ID: ";
    cin >> searchId;

    if (searchId < 0 || searchId > 9999) {
        cout << "Your student ID must be in between 0 and 9999! Try again...\n";
    }

    } while (searchId < 0 || searchId > 9999);

    readGrades.open("grades.txt");

    if (readGrades)
    {
        system("cls");

        while (readGrades >> studentId >> examGrade1 >> examGrade2 >> examGrade3)
        {
            if (searchId == studentId)
            {
                cout << left
                    << "Student ID\t" << "Exam 1\t" << "Exam 2\t" << "Exam 3\t" << endl;
                cout << "======================================" << endl;
                cout << left << setw(4) << studentId << "\t\t"
                    << fixed << setprecision(2)
                    << left << setw(5) << examGrade1 << "\t"
                    << left << setw(5) << examGrade2 << "\t"
                    << left << setw(5) << examGrade3 << endl;
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
            else
                cout << "Entered ID not found";
        }   
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file!\n";
    }

    cout << endl; }
```

Now the problem is the else statement. I am supposed to prompt to the user that a certain ID doesn't exist. But I don't know how to make the else statement only run once in the while statement. Every time I search a non-existing ID, it will say "Entered ID not found" for however many times it reads the inputs.

So the results look something like this.
[No ID Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egiAn.png)

At the same time, if I enter an ID that does exist but it's third in the file, it will look something like this. [ID Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhbRn.png)

I know logically what is happening, it keeps running the while loop for however many times. But I don't know how to deal with the problem. Any help to lead me to the right direction would be helpful. I'm new to coding/C++ and not too familiar with searching for something inside a file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` block is in the wrong place. You need to update your logic such that you print that message only if the student ID is not found after going through the entire file. Which means, it has be outside the `while` loop.

```
if (readGrades)
{
    bool found = false;
    while (readGrades >> studentId >> examGrade1 >> examGrade2 >> examGrade3)
    {
        if (searchId == studentId)
        {
            cout << left
                << "Student ID\t" << "Exam 1\t" << "Exam 2\t" << "Exam 3\t" << endl;
            cout << "======================================" << endl;
            cout << left << setw(4) << studentId << "\t\t"
                << fixed << setprecision(2)
                << left << setw(5) << examGrade1 << "\t"
                << left << setw(5) << examGrade2 << "\t"
                << left << setw(5) << examGrade3 << endl;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    } 

    if ( !found )
    {
       cout << "Entered ID not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I actually tried this method but forgot to enter the if (!found) outside of the while statement... I don't know why I was stumped with this for the past hour. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @ThatOneGoi, judging from "my" past, you'll probably commit similar faux pas a few more times :)

Comment: oh no... oh well as long as it makes me learn, I don't mind them at all lmao